# Assigning default value of mat-button-toggle-group from an object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to set the initial `value` of `mat-button-toggle-group` from an object but I can't seem set it.

This is my template:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group
   #stateFilters="matButtonToggleGroup"
   class="calendar-view-toggle"
   [value]="postsFilters.state"
   (change)="changePostsStateFilter(stateFilters.value)"
>
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="[postState.draft]">Drafts</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle
     [value]="[postState.awaitingApproval,postState.approvedFirst,postState.approvedSecond]"
   >
       Pending Approval
   </mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="[postState.approved]">Approved</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

This is my TS File:

```
export class CalendarListComponent {
    postsFilters: IPostFilters = {
        state: [EPostState.draft],
        onlyToBeApprovedByMe: false,
    };

    changePostsStateFilter(states: EPostState[]) {
        this.postsFilters.state = states;
        this.loadPosts(this.postsFilters.state, 0);
    }
}

export interface IPostFilters {
  state?: EPostState[];
  onlyToBeApprovedByMe?: boolean;
}
```

If anyone could give me some help that would be great!

Comment: Can you create stackblitz with dummy value for this? I'll be able to help you with that

Answer (score 0):

you can use enum for better readability

you can update selectedState with appropriate value depending on result

```
export enum PostEnum {
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3
}

export class CalendarListComponent {
    postEnum: typeof PostEnum = PostEnum;
    selectedState = PostEnum.Option1;
}

<mat-button-toggle-group
   [value]="selectedState"
   (change)="changePostsStateFilter()">
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="postEnum.Option1">Drafts</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="postEnum.Option2">Pending Approval</mat-button-toggle>
   <mat-button-toggle [value]="postEnum.Option3">Approved</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-toggle-group